# React Native - I want import 2 component with same name

Tags: android, react-native, mobile, import

I want to import 2 files from same name when we are importing.
like (It's Possible?):

```
import en from './en';
import en from './en';
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your example, why would you want to import the same component from the same module twice?
If that is indeed what you wanted to do, you could do it as following:

`import * as UniqueName1 from "./en"`

`import * as UniqueName2 from "./en"`